# How to view the actual implementation of C++ headers?

Tags: c++, header

Is it possible to view the under the hood implementation of certain C++ libraries and how?

For example, I would like to see how `std::map` is implemented. I know it is a balanced tree (red-black tree) but I would like to see the actual implementation. Is this possible?

Comment: libc++ and libstdc++ are both open source.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Compiler are allowed to not have **files** for system header as `<map>` though. (compiler may have a internal cache for example).

Comment: @Jarod42 I had never encountered that, thank you for the correction.

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits

Comment: The implementation may very well be specialised for certain key types.

Answer (score -1):

You need the source. For things in glibc (or other open source libraries), that should be available.